# missing return statement error when using multiple methods

Tags: java, methods

I have an assignment where we make a bunch of different methods based on uml. the uml looks like this +add2Nums(iX1:int,iX2:int):int and my code looks like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class proj2
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    add2Nums(2,3);



} //End main

public static int add2Nums(int iX1, int iX2)
{


}//End add2Nums

}//End proj2
```

I get an error saying i am missing a return statement, however if i change the type from int to void in the method declaration, it will compile but this goes against what the uml is telling me to do. I feel like im missing something super important, can anyone tell me whats going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should simply *return* something (`int` in your case) in your `add2Nums` method as the compiler tells you:

```
public static int add2Nums(int iX1, int iX2)
{
    int num = iX1 + iX2;
    return num;    //this is what you are missing
}
```

Your method signature has `int` type:

```
public static int add2Nums(int iX1, int iX2) //note the "[int] add2Nums"
```

Thus, the compiler expects the method block to have `return` the same data type/its parent type (`int` or its parent types) in all possible paths of the code.

Answer (score 1):

> you method signature says it is going to return an integer value. But
>   you do not return anything from within your method, hence the error.

```
public static int add2Nums(int iX1, int iX2)
{
    return iX1 +  iX2;

}
```